# Writing ID3v2 metadata using TagLib

Tags: c++, mp3, metadata, taglib

I am writing a music ripper and have been at it for some days now. Everything is working as it should except setting metadata. I am downloading raw PCM data, encoding to MP3 using ffmpeg.exe and then setting metadata to the file. I know ffmpeg.exe can write metadata but it does not suit my needs as i cannot write the character (") when specifying the metadata in the command line. Also, ffmpeg.exe cuts my data to a maximum of 30 characters, which also is my problem when using TagLib:

```
TagLib::FileRef f("some_mp3.mp3");

f.tag()->setArtist("Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Artist");
f.tag()->setAlbum("Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Album");
f.tag()->setTitle("Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Title");
f.tag()->setTrack(37);

f.save();
```

It seems this code is using ID3v1 since it crops the long strings to just 30 characters, yes i did read some Wikipedia on this :P I need it to use ID3v2 to give long data. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As i get it from the ffmpeg documentation ffmpeg.exe uses the lame codec. Thus you might want to check how to configure lame instead of ffmpeg. Lame has options for ID3 Tags, take a look hat their homepage here: http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/USAGE

Comment: The encoding goes fine, i just need to set the metadata. This can be and is in my case, a separate pass. I am currently looking at ID3lib where i can set long text values but i am having problems setting UTF-8 texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class TagLib::MPEG::File to open the file and the ID3v2Tag to get the ID3v2 tag.
Your code will become this:

```
  TagLib::MPEG::File f("some_mp3.mp3");
  f.ID3v2Tag()->setArtist("Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Artist");
  f.ID3v2Tag()->setAlbum("Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Album");
  f.ID3v2Tag()->setTitle("Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Title");
  f.ID3v2Tag()->setTrack(37);
  f.save();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Still cuts the strings to 30 characters. Any other library capable of setting these four kinds of metadata with long strings could also work for me, if no other solution comes around :)

Comment: I just found that both codes seem to store the whole string yet Windows Explorer and my MP3 player only shows the first 30 characters. If i set the metadata with Windows Explorer it shows up full length on my MP3 player and of course in Windows. So i guess i want to do the same in code.

Comment: Ahh, "Windows Explorer and Windows Media Player cannot handle ID3v2 version 2.4 tags in any version, up to and including Windows 7/Windows Media Player 12.[5] Windows can understand ID3v2 up to and including version 2.3" It seems i need specifically ID3v2.3, right..